# python imaplib mail.search; without reply emails

Tags: python, email, search, imaplib, reply

I'm making a script for searching emails and downloading attachments.
It works well, but I encountered a problem when an email fits the criteria but is a reply to another email.

I want to select only the emails that are no replies.

Below is my code.

```
#connect to imap server
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
mail.login(username, password)

result, data = mail.search(None, '(FROM "email-address" SUBJECT "subject")')
```

Could I maybe add something to the mail.search line so that it ignores replies?
I'm actually pretty new to this python module so help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good news. Visiting this page [IMAP Commands](https://www.atmail.com/blog/imap-commands/) you will find the command you are looking for under SEARCH.

IMAP flag to search for:

```
ANSWERED
    Messages with the \Answered flag set.
```

So an example of the RAW search string you need to send is:

```
SC01 SEARCH ANSWERED
```

And with your Python example, probably:

```
result, data = mail.search(None, '(ANSWERED)')
```

Here is another great resource for Python `imaplib`:

[imaplib - IMAP4 client library](https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/)

Comment: That’s assuming it’s set by clients.  It’s based on the \Answered flag, which can be set when a client replies to an email (not must), but has nothing to do with their further replies, or if _someone else_ replied to it.  This is a bit outside of the IMAP search language, which only can consider emails in isolation.

Comment: Long overdue, but thank you for the replies!